# Presence autoload in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, autoload, bootstrapping

Similar feature as:

```
function __autoload(UndefinedClass)
 {
  include 'library/'.UndefinedClass.'.php';
 }
?>
```

Python package = _init.py, BIOS=MBR, C++= STIL or templates, PHP5 = autoload, but python 3.x ?

Comment: And what does that do? Everything is autoloaded in Python. Can you explain what you actually want to do? When asking a quetsion explain What you are doing, what you expect it to do, what is happening, and why you want to do it in the first place.

Comment: @Lennart: Either of us must be misinformed about PHP's autoloading or about Python's module system and `import` mechanism. Python only imports what you tell it to import, and when something is not defined, it won't attempt to fix that but throw an error.

Comment: Yes, but this is not a problem that needs fixing, so that's not what he is asking for, which is why I asked for clarification. It's possibly one of us has misunderstood the autoload feature, and it might be me, I thought it was for when you needed to reference classes or modules that wasn't defined yet. A sort of predefine to avoid circularity. Your comment seems to indicate that it magically searches in the libraries whenever you get a NameError. That would be horrid. :)

Comment: And of course, no followup from the newbie. It's so annoying.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature, because you don't need it. If you want to not import a module until it's needed, then you just import it when it's needed. If you want to avoid circular imports, you do pretty much the same thing.

There, now this question has an answer. :-)

Comment: But automatic import of other modules without typing "import" statement(in each file different) is not possible ? ;-)

Comment: @Michal: I might be possible. But you don't want to do that, anyway. Just import it.

Comment: i guess he wants something similar to <?php $mod = factory::model("ModelName"); ?>